# Automapper IEnumerable<something> to IEnumerable<somethingelse> without creating a map configuration

Tags: c#, automapper-3

I cannot get the following to work, where array is an array of CustomerContract's:

```
Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Customer>>(array);

Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CustomerContract>, IEnumerable<Customer>>(array);

Mapper.Map<Array, List<Customer>>(array);
```

In my mind the first example should be enough, but i can not get either to work. I have read the configuration wiki of automapper (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration), but i do not understand why this should be necessary. 
Everything Automapper needs is defined in the command. Which type it is (both object and that it is a list), and which object i want it to map to.

Am i just not understanding the core concept of Automapper?

My exception sounds like this:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>   Mapping types:\r\nCustomerContract -> Customer\r\nStimline.Xplorer.Repository.CustomerService.CustomerContract -> Stimline.Xplorer.BusinessObjects.Customer
>   Destination path: List`1[0]
>   Source value: Stimline.Xplorer.Repository.CustomerService.CustomerContract

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're mapping to IEnumerable... Automapper can map to a concrete type not an interface.

First register your mapping (see the "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping")
You must use CreateMap once for performance

```
Mapper.CreateMap<something, somethingelse>();
```

Instead of:

```
Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Customer>>(array);
```

Try this:

```
Mapper.Map<List<Customer>>(array);
```

or

```
Mapper.Map<Customer[]>(array);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But i still don't understand why i need to create the map... it should be able to determine all of the info CreateMap is giving it from the inputs of the Mapper.Map<List<Customer>>(array)... why does it not?

Comment: @Swell, my understanding is that autoMapper support all the generic collection types. To be specific here's the list: IEnumerable, IEnumerable<T>, ICollection, ICollection<T>, IList, IList<T>, List<T>, Arrays.

Comment: @BjørnØyvindHalvorsen because CreateMap is actually a slow method... If CreateMap was called everytime you call Map it would kill your application performance

Comment: @Bayeni it's true, but when you ask IEnumerable<T> as the destination what Automapper is supposed to return? Collection<T>? List<T>?

Comment: it will return the IEnumerable<DestinationType>, ie. IEnumerable<DestinationType> ienumerableDest = Mapper.Map<SourceType[], IEnumerable<DestinationType>>(sources); Thanks Swell